# get the list of code changes from visual source safe

Tags: visual-studio, scripting, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am trying to get the list of changes made to a file in source safe through the command line? Is there a source safe command or tools to do this? For example, let's say I have a file named 
testing.vb. In that file, I changed only the following text from

```
Dim temp as String
```

to

```
Dim temp as Double
```

I am looking for a tool or a source safe command that would get this information. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

From Google and MSDN: [Diff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230394%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and 
[Diff (file)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9a7z21t6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)